# Show that if $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha > 0$ at $x$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$

Tags: calculus, lipschitz-functions

> A function is called Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ at $x$ if there is a constant $C>0$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$ for all $y$ in an open interval containing $x$. Show that if $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha > 0$ at $x$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Since $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha > 0$ at $x$, we have that there exists a constant $C > 0$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$. Now to show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ we have to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to x} f(y) = f(x)$. The Lipschitz form seems to limit how fast the function can grow, so I need to somehow relate that to the definition of the limit but I am unsure how to.

Comment: Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$  such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$. An obvious bound follows by choosing $\delta$ appropriately. In terms of limits you must show $\lim_{y\to x}f(y) =f(x)$ NOT $\lim_{y\to x} f(y)=x$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 We must also have that the limit equals the value of the function at that point. Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: that is precisely what the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition means when $c\in D$ where $D$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 What i'm saying is that we also need the value of the function at $x$ to equal the limit of the function at $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;\epsilon>0\;$ and choose $\;\delta=\sqrt[\alpha]\frac\epsilon C\;$  ( observe that it is given $\;\alpha>0\;$ ), so

$$|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\stackrel{\text{given}}<C|x-y|^\alpha<C\delta^\alpha=C\frac\epsilon C=\epsilon$$

and this implies $\;f(y)\xrightarrow[y\to x]{}f(x)\;$ and we've finished

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $f$ is continuous at $x_o$ if $\forall ϵ>0$,  there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x- x_o| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_o)| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given and let $y \in B_{\delta}(x) \Rightarrow |x - y| < \delta$

Then $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x- y|^{\alpha} < C\delta^{\alpha}$

Pick $\delta = {(\dfrac{\epsilon}{C})}^{1/\alpha}$

Then it follows $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

**Lipschitz implies continuity**

"Drill baby drill!"